# How to convert the existing project with SCSS Support project?

Tags: angular, typescript, saas

I have a angaular cli application.Now i want to make it compatible with sass.But it is not happening.

This is my .ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry';
}
```

I run a code ng set defaults.styleExt scss in commad line
Then it is updated in the angular.cli.json.Then i renamed the app.component.css to app.component.scss manually.

My .css file is like this.

```
$primary-color:red;

.head{
   color: $primary-color; 
}
```

My .html file is below

```
<div class="head">
  {{title}}
</div>
```

But while compiling i am getting error.
The error is as below
cant resolve app.component.scss.Field browser doesnt contain a valid alias configuration.Please help me.Thanks in advance?

Comment: Did you use angular cli

Answer (score 0):

First, change the CSS file extensions in `angular-cli.json` :

```
"defaults": {
  "styleExt": "scss",
  "component": {}
}
```

next, rename your file !

```
app.component.css --> app.component.scss
```

**EDIT** Did you try turning it off and on again ? Relaunch `ng serve` !

Comment: Yeah, I thought so too, but from the question, it seems like OP did all that.

Comment: Written in bold, right after **EDIT** ? Refresh the page if you don't see it

Comment: .ts i made styleUrl as  app.component.scss but not working